# Regex to get lbs and ozs i.e. 16lb 4ozs and it's variations

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I am trying to get a regex pattern to match the following for lbs and ozs, I am 50% of the way there having used : https://regex101.com/ to get this far:

[image: Regex Pattern at regex101]

- 6lb14ozs
- 6 lb 14ozs
- 6 lb 14ozs
- 6 lb 14 ozs
- 6 lbs 14ozs
- 6 lb 14ozs
- 69 lb 14ozs
- 6lb 14 ozs
- 6lb14 ozs
- 6 lb14 ozs
- 66lb14ozs
- 66 lb14ozs
- 65 lb 14ozs
- 66lb1ozs
- 66 lb1ozs
- 65 lb 1ozs
- 6lb14oz
- 6 lb14oz
- 6 lb 14oz
- 6 lb 14 oz
- 6lb 14 oz
- 6lb14 oz
- 6 lb14 oz
- 100lb 13ozs

The pattern i am using is:

```
/(\d|\d\d|\d\d\d)\s*(?:lb|lbs)[^\s]?\s\d?\d\s*(oz|ozs)?[^\s]/g
```

i am sure it can be done better and more efficiently too.

Comment: What are you trying to extract? The pair of numbers?

Comment: the ultimate goal is to convert these into kilograms but for now i just want to get all the matches out as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `[0-9]+[ ]*lbs?[ ]*[0-9]+[ ]*ozs?`

In your attempt, you're making the units optional, so it'll probably match stuff you don't want it to match. Make the 's' optional instead.

Cheers,
Paulo

To capture the numbers, you'd need `([0-9]+)[ ]*lbs?[ ]*([0-9]+)[ ]*ozs?`.

To convert into kg, in Python you'd have (your data's in `test_str`):

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'([0-9]+)[ ]*lbs?[ ]*(\d+)\s*ozs?')
test_str = "6lb14ozs\n6 lb 14ozs\n6 lb 14ozs\n6 lb 14 ozs\n6 lbs 14ozs\n6 lb 14ozs\n69 lb 14ozs\n6lb 14 ozs\n6lb14 ozs\n6 lb14 ozs\n66lb14ozs\n66 lb14ozs\n65 lb 14ozs\n66lb1ozs\n66 lb1ozs\n65 lb 1ozs\n6lb14oz\n6 lb14oz\n6 lb 14oz\n6 lb 14 oz\n6lb 14 oz\n6lb14 oz\n6 lb14 oz\n100lb 13ozs"

for i in re.findall(p, test_str):
    print float(i[0]) * 0.45 + float(i[1]) * 0.02
```

**UPDATE**

This version matches isolated lb(s) and oz(s), but the 's' isn't matched so the last 2 characters of each matched measurement can be used to determine the unit and make the conversion. The new regex is easier to read as well.

```
import re
p = re.compile(r"(\d+\s*lb)?s?\s*(\d+\s*oz)?s?\n")    

test_str = "6lb14ozs\n6 lb 14ozs\n6 lb 14ozs\n6 lb 14 ozs\n6 lbs 14ozs\n6 lb 14ozs\n69 lb 14ozs\n6lb 14 ozs\n6lb14 ozs\n6 lb14 ozs\n66lb14ozs\n66 lb14ozs\n65 lb 14ozs\n66lb1ozs\n66 lb1ozs\n65 lb 1ozs\n6lb14oz\n6 lb14oz\n6 lb 14oz\n6 lb 14 oz\n6lb 14 oz\n6lb14 oz\n6 lb14 oz\n100lb 13ozs"

for j in re.findall(p, test_str):
    print (sum ([int (i[:-2]) * {"lb":0.45, "oz":0.02}[i[-2:]] for i in j]))
```

Comment: this looks efficient too...only 328 steps.

Comment: i ended up using ([0-9]+)[ ]*lbs?[ ]*([0-9]+)[ ]*ozs? and converted it to get kilos values too with ([0-9]?[]\.|\,]?[0-9]+)[ ]*kgs? (note on this one i also looked for the , as well as the .)

Comment: On debugging this is't not picking up a single item for example 18lb or 8lb. How can i make that second group optional: https://regex101.com/r/iA4mU2/2 admittedly i missed this out from the original question

Comment: Just put the segment corresponding to oz between parentheses followed by a `?`. I've updated the regex in the link.You'd have to tweak the unit conversion code as well, of course.

Comment: Thanks but i don't think you saved the updated version. But i think it should be like this right? [0-9]+[ ]*lbs?[ ]*([0-9]+[ ]*ozs?)?

Comment: Yes, that's it. You can do the same thing to the lb/lbs segment if you have lines that are just pound(s).

Answer (score 2):

```
\d+\s*lbs?\s*\d+\s*ozs?



\d+     One or more digits

\s*     Zero or more spaces

lbs?    lb or lbs

\s*     Zero or more spaces

\d+     One or more digits

\s*     Zero or more spaces

ozs?    oz or ozs
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
\s*(\d+)\s*(lbs|lb)\s*(\d+)\s*(ozs|oz)
```

should work.

Capture groups 0 and 2 will contains the amounts.

Comment: your method may be more effective for my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
(\d+)\D+(\d+)\D+
```

It captures the two numeric groups, and bypasses anything non numeric.

Use the g flag.